# nearby message api is not calling onFound method for beacon

Tags: android, beacon, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I am trying to use beacons in my project. Initially all was going well. I was able to register beacon and listen all attachments from it in my application but Now I am facing an issue.

I have registered one beacon(device used of BKON comapny) with google in my project using BeaconTools app and provide attachments to it.

Now, build GoogleApiClient in Android app, subscribe beacon with Nearby Message api and written code for listen Nearby messages.

Initially I was getting all attachments but now after successfully subscribed, I am not able to listen any single attachment.

I have already registered beacon with my project, enable Nearby Message API in the project.

I don't know why I am getting this issue because earlier I was getting all right things but now beacon is only subscribed successfully and after that I am not getting anything. Please provide me the solution, My client is waiting.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: provide some code basis.

Comment: Are you certain the beacon is transmitting?  Can you detect the beacon with an off the shelf detector app like Locate? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en

Comment: @AashishSharma Have you found the cause?

Comment: No, I didn't find the cause. I have used Locate app too and its detecting beacon successfully but using Nearby from Google I am not able to find the beacon.